# Como fazer média em SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho um trabalho para fazer aonde eu insiro nome e duas notas em um banco de dados utilizando VoiceXML. Tenho duas tabelas, uma com `nome`, `notaum`, `notadois` e outra com `nome`, `media`. Como eu faço pra calcular a média de `notaum` e `notadois` e inserir na outra tabela?

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer?

Comment: Eu tentei pesquisar como fazer isso, porque minhas habilidades com SQL são quase nulas. Mas código eu ainda não fiz.

Comment: @LuizFernandoElesbão A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 5):

Isso?

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.media = (t2.notaum + t2.notadois) / 2
    FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.nome = t2.nome;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/AverageOtherTable.sql).